# Which commercial staff vacation/absence/holiday/leave planner with workflow?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, calendar, business

I am looking for a **commercial staff vacation planner** with the following features:

- is compatible with **SharePoint 2013** Standard Edition
- allows **multiple managers to approve** an employee's request
- **skips holidays** and weekends; a request from friday to monday should result in two days of vacation taken (not in four)

I've searched for solutions but most of them require an additional account at a website.

**Q: What products can you recommend?**

Answer (score 2):

Threre is a free workflow tool called Datapolis Process System - Basic,  which allows you to build such a planner in hours. This is generic graphical workflow designer, but very powerful and multiple approvals, date calculations etc. are very easy to obtain. You can take it here: basic.datapolis.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution here, but we recently launched [LeaveDates](https://www.leavedates.com) which would work well for you. It is a staff holiday planner with automated approval workflows like you requested. It will also correctly calculate holidays which span a weekend or public holiday. I'm not quite sure what you mean by Sharepoint 2013 compatibility but a customer recently told me the following, which makes me think it is...

"We have been able to place a link on our Sharepoint home calendar which allows employees to directly book off that calendar."

Hope this helps.